# Loading json data from file in python

Tags: python, json, file, load

I was saving data from a webpage with the following code:

```
[...]
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
data_to_analyse = json.loads(the_page)
import datetime
datafile = open(str(datetime.datetime.now())+'_data.json','w')
datafile.write(str(data_to_analyse))
[...]
```

Now I try to work with data saved in datafile, but I can't handle the json correct.

**datafile start example part**:

```
{
    u'SiteRep': {
                  u'DV': {
                           u'type': u'Obs', 
                           u'dataDate': u'2016-11-18T10:00:00Z', 
                           u'Location': [
                                            {
                                                u'elevation': u'15.0',
                                                u'name': u'BALTASOUND',
                                                u'i': u'3002'
[and so on - file closes correct...]
```

Before I could simple process 'data_to_analyse' with:

```
for SiteRep in data_to_analyse:
    for data_to_analyse_experience in data_to_analyse[SiteRep]:
```

and everything worked. Now I receive the error:

```
**TypeError:** string indices must be integers, not str
```

if i try to load the data from the file with that code:

```
for datafile in os.listdir('.'):
    if datafile.endswith('.json'):
        data = open(datafile,'r').read()

        jsondata = json.dumps(data)
```

or:

```
**ValueError:** Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

with:

```
        jsondata = json.loads(data)
```

How to convert the file into a correct json object?

Answer (score 2):

Try with this

```
import json

with open('strings.json') as json_data:
 d = json.load(json_data)
 print(d)
```

Comment: The result is:
    ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

Comment: You may want to wrap your json.load line with a try catch because invalid JSON will cause a stacktrace error message.

Answer (score 0):

Actually [JSON ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25707558/json-valueerror-expecting-property-name-line-1-column-2-char-1/41260034#41260034) solved the problem by:

```
    data_to_analyse = open(datafile,'r').read()
    data_to_analyse = data_to_analyse.replace("'",'"')
    data_to_analyse = data_to_analyse.replace("u\"",'"')
    jsondata = json.loads(data_to_analyse)
```