# Flask failing with apostrophes

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, request

If a `'` is used within the newName header value everything works okay, however, if `’` is used, for example, the server fails to handle the request.

I'm debugging some larger code, but have created a minimalist version that is subject to the same problem.

```
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/dave', methods=['POST'])
def hello():
    newName=request.headers['newName']
    return newName

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host= '0.0.0.0', debug=True)
    app.debug = True
```

I am using Postman to debug. If I send " David's " everything works as intended, however, if I send "David’s" it fails, and nothing seems to show up in the error log (although I may be missing a trick).

Comment: Understandable, an HTTP header must not contain a ’ .

Comment: Why are you sending data in headers anyway? Content should be in the body of the POST.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments I've neglected to realise that headers should not contain ’. Data should therefore be sent within the POST body, rather than the header.

Example: [How to get data received in Flask request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434599/how-to-get-data-received-in-flask-request)

Single quotes can be an issue with Python and JSON, apparently. This appears to solve that problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/36599122/5152133